# close and reopen modal extra click event trigger again when I do click on toggle button (in re-opened modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that open and close properly but when I re-open the modal, and do click on toggle button extra click event fire(means total two click event on single click).

```
//open modal close modal
$("#my-id").modal('show', {
    backdrop: 'static'
});
$("#my-id").modal('hide');

//toggle button code
<input id="togle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"  >

//javascript
$('#togle').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
     $(this).val("1");
  } else {
     $(this).val("0");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

toggle button click to add $('#my-id').modal('toggle');

Try This :

```
//open modal close modal
$("#my-id").modal('show', {
    backdrop: 'static'
});
$("#my-id").modal('hide');

//toggle button code
<input id="togle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"  >

//javascript
$('#togle').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $(this).val("1");
    } else {
        $(this).val("0");
    }
    $('#my-id').modal('toggle')
});
```